# Is there anyway to align text to center in multi-line label for all lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**Thanks for your time.**

Here is the final effect:

[image: screenshot1]

I am doing it with multi-line label (.textAligement = NSTextAlignmentCenter &  .lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping), and looks like this so far： [image: screenshot1]:)

Here is the sample code:

```
NSArray *detailTimePointsArray = @[@"08:00",@"08:05",@"08:10",@"08:15",@"08:20",
                                   @"08:25",@"08:30",@"08:35",@"08:40",@"08:45",
                                   @"08:50",@"08:55",@"09:00",@"09:05",@"09:10",
                                   @"09:15",@"09:20",@"09:25",@"10:00",@"10:05",
                                   @"10:10",@"10:15",@"10:20",@"10:25",@"10:35",
                                   @"10:40",@"10:45",@"10:50",@"10:55",@"11:25"];

UILabel *detailTimeInfoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
detailTimeInfoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
detailTimeInfoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
detailTimeInfoLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

detailTimeInfoLabel.text = [detailTimePointsArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

[self addSubview:detailTimeInfoLabel];
```

Maybe it`s a better choice to do it with UICollectionView, but i am wandering is it possible to make it happen with label or some other controls more lightweight?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you shwo ur code

Comment: Did you try adding spacer strings between those strings ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Sorry for not knowing how to 'add spacer strings between those strings', could you show me the way?

Comment: I mean to say add empty strings with blank sapces like @"     " in between those values.

Comment: Another solution would be to use one label for each component and display them in the desired layout.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks for the suggestion, but it will bring other layout problems and not do the trick. UICollectionView is the winner finally :)

Answer (score 0):

What you try to accomplish is called text justify. UILabel does not support it.

You can try some 3rd party text kits, but I personally would go with a `UICollectionView`. It may feel like an overkill, but at least it's easy to setup and manage in future.

Comment: yeah ,i agree with you, UICollectionView is a better solution in the long term. just wandering :)